# Wrong encoding of dynamic block properties problem

Tags: json

After update to 5.5.1 German umlauts in dynamic block properties ( strings ) are incorrectly encoded/saved in the database.

Something like this as request:

```
<!-- wp:hsu/mitarbeiterblock {"dataPostanschrift":["Universität","Fakultät für Elektrotechnik",""],
```

becomes (response & db):

```
<!-- wp:hsu/mitarbeiterblock {"dataPostanschrift":["Universitu00e4t","Fakultu00e4t fu00fcr Elektrotechnik",""]
```

To reproduce, modify a request and insert umlauts like öäü in properties of a block.

Is there something to solve this?

Comment: Does this happen with all blocks, or just this custom block?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there a core dynamic block? Content in blocks like p is fine.

Comment: Works, but just als (Super)Administrator. This problem comes up if it#s done with an editor account.

Comment: You should edit this into your first answer, not post it as a second answer.  It does not stand alone as an answer.

Comment: @sosere do not post replies as answers unless your reply is the solution to your question. I know you can't leave comments as a user with only 1 rep, but that doesn't mean you should abuse the system to get around it. If you need to add information to your question, you can use the `edit` link to edit it in

Answer (score 0):

Solved myself. The rest response ist fine. Important is not the raw response but the json encoded representation. Couse of my problem war editing the files with vi. VI reencoded the files itself. PHP & JS files need to be encoded as utf8.